# How to keep a single FRAGMENT to view Multiple WebPages

Tags: android, xml, listview, fragment

Hello Friends i'm using a listView on listitem click program execute the bellow code but as Listview having many listitem which will call **DIFFERENT WEBPAGES**
has For the Different Webpages i have to create Different Fragment.xml and Framgment.java  file ??? or i can keep a common fragment and xml file and with the help of list item state i can call different webpages !!!
Please Help me with this 
As i'm beginner in android
Thank You

Fragment.xml

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewabout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Fragment.java

```
 package com.ft.bscit;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    import com.ft.bscit.R;

    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class About_bscit_Fragment extends Fragment {


        public About_bscit_Fragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_bscit, container, false);

            WebView webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewabout);

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

            return rootView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating your fragment? Paste that code.

Comment: have posted the Fragment Instantiating in answer section below

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `url` while instantiating your fragment.

```
case R.id.button1:
                        //what to put here
                         About_bscit_Fragment fragment = About_bscit_Fragment.newInstance("your-url-value");
                        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                        ft.commit();
                        break;
                }
```

where `newInstance()` is defined in `About_bscit_Fragment` -

```
public static About_bscit_Fragment newInstance(String url) {
        About_bscit_Fragment fragment = new About_bscit_Fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("key_url", url);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

In  Fragment's `onViewCreated()` you can fetch the values you sent while instantiating it -

```
String url = getArguments().getString("key_url");
```

And load it -

```
 webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: bro not exactly getting what to do can you please edit the upper ans which i had posted

Comment: There is no space between new and Instance. I edited the answer.

Comment: where to load webView.load(url)??

Comment: In onViewCreated() .

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.forever.technology.bscit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.forever.technology.bscit.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Sem1Fragment_list extends ListFragment {




    public Sem1Fragment_list() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sem1_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.sem1, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Subject1Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            case 1:

        }

    }
}
```